# Central AC Unit not blowing cold air

Tags: hvac

OK, so my Central AC Unit has acted a little funny shortly after I purchased the house I'm in now. It worked fine besides occasionally when I would try and drop the thermostat multiple degrees at a time, example: I leave for work so I put it up to 76 or so then when I come home I'd drop it down 73 and it would start blowing cold but then after it dropped a degree or so it would just blow regular non-cooled air and then it would climb back up to 78 Degrees until I noticed. In the past I would just shut it off, wait maybe 20 min and flip it back on and lower it one degree at a time. Well, it's just gotten worse and now it won't drop below 77 degrees. I've checked the drip pan on the inside unit thinking it must need to be drained but it looks bone dry like there has not been any water in there for a good while. Also, it appears the PVC pipe you would uncap to drain it is glued on with adhesive. The only other pipe I really have access to that has a cap that's not glued on is attached, my next guess is its clogged so I'm thinking a Shop-Vac maybe could pull the clog out. I'm no expert so if anyone has advice plz lmk. Also, I've changed the filter and I live in Florida to give you an idea of the weather conditions.
[[image: Image One][1]]

Comment: When you say it is blowing regular non-cooled air, is it blowing with as much force as normal? Because if it is not, and especially if it is just barely blowing, then your coils are freezing up, and this is an indication that your refrigerant is low. This would match your description of being able to cool a degree or two, but not being able to cool several degrees at a time.

Comment: Follow Glen Yates suggestion assuming the filter is clean.

Comment: As much force as normal yes, just not cold. It's night time now here and thankfully around 72 outside so I should be able to sleep tonight and go look at it tomorrow in the day light, I posted this right before heading to work so just now reading it. I was told to pour warm water down the pvc pipe in the picture with no cap on it (all the others are glued on) and have someone watch the outside drainage pipe to see if it poured out or dripped out or just completly backs up then if it is clogged take a shop vac to that outside drainage pipe and suck it out. If that doesn't work I'll be back, lol